# D3.js CSV Chart Plotting With Unknown Headers

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, charts

I am trying to plot a chart in D3.js using is native CSV parser [ d3.csv() - https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV ]

An example of a grouped bar chart plotted via d3.csv() is here - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

The issue I am facing is that I am unable to get the chart working when the headers in the CSV are unknown.

For example in the above example the chart works only if the headers in the CSV file is

`State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over`

If I use the headers like

`Year,Age,Gender`

then the chart does not work. The chart needs to be working with any kind of CSV files with any headers.

Would appreciate any help to build a dynamic chart with unknown headers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this.

```
function glow(i){
d3.csv("inputs/conData.csv",function(data){

//CSV File parsing
    var gl = [];

    var keys = Object.keys(data[0]);
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        gl.push(d[keys[i]]);
    });
}
```

This function will accept the column number as an argument for which the header needs to be returned.

Reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/dAfM2Mk_NWY